# Cloning an Array without some fields

Tags: reactjs

I have an array like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIpfc.png), but i want to have copy of this array but without fields: name and price. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible implementation to achieve the objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const origArr = [
  { id: 0, name: 'name1', amount: 10, price: 33.9 },
  { id: 1, name: 'name2', amount: 20, price: 24.9 }
];

const transformArray = arr => (
  arr.map(
    ({name, price, amount, ...rest}) => ({
      ...rest,
      quantity: amount
    })
  )
);

console.log(transformArray(origArr));
```

**Explanation**

- Iterate through the `origArr`
- De-structure the object to pick the `name`, `price`, `amount` props
- Transform by excluding `name`, `price` & renaming `amount` to `quantity`